# How to join data correctly on 'Date' column in ADF?

Tags: azure, date, join, azure-data-factory

I want to combine two tables in a data flow of Azure Data Factory. So I tried to join the tables using the 'Date' column as join condition:

[image]

I would suspect the output of this join only has 1 'Date' column. But it has actually 2 'Date' columns:

[image]

It seems it doesn't recognize it as the same sort of column?? The result of this is that all the dates are duplicated (not visible here in ADF because it only samples random data, but this is visible in for example powerbi when you load all the data).

Can somebody explain me what is happening and how I should fix it?

Comment: Did any of the below answers help your question?

Answer (score 1):

When you say combine, do you plan to have all your dates in just one column? If yes, then use [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/data-flow-union) instead of Join.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems it doesn't recognize it as the same sort of column??

In a `JOIN` operation, the Data Flow automaticaly retains the columns from both the left and right hand sides of the `JOIN`.

If you need to combine any to a single column, use the `Derive column` action in your flow to calculate a singular value for each row (an expression akin to `iifNull(AggregateByDayObeya@Date, AggregateByDateFDQ2@Date)` should suffice), then run a `Select columns` action to remove any unnecessary columns you don't need.